# quad with mvnpdf involves vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I tried to run the following code:

```
F=@(x)mvnpdf([6 x],[0 0],[1 0;0 1]);
P=quad(F,12,100);
```

to get the probability integration of `x2` from 12 to 100 of a joint Gaussian distribution.
However matlab report this error:

> X and MU must have the same number of columns.

It's very strange to me because when I run `F(1)`,`F(2)`, or something similar it runs correctly.

Why is there an error when I use quad to integrate the `mvnpdf` function.?

Why is the parameter `quad`, given to the function F, not a scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `quad` passes a vector of values to `F`, and not a single value. You need to handle that in your `F`, e.g. like this

```
F = @(X)mvnpdf([repmat(6, size(X(:),1), 1) X(:)],[0,0],[1,0;0,1]);
```

I have simply repeated the number 6 as many times, as there are rows in vector `X`. Note that `X` needs to be a column vector, that's why I explicitly convert it to such by `X(:)`. Now you can write

```
F(1:100)
```

without getting an error.

Comment: Thank you very much, @angainor! It's works now. I assume that the working principle of function quad is firstly calculated the function result of vector X contains many x, you get a Y, and secondly the integration is gained by Y*delta(x).