# MATLAB - integral2 and mvnpdf

Tags: matlab

I know this question has been asked in a 1D form before (see [quad with mvnpdf involves vector in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688759/quad-with-mvnpdf-involves-vector-in-matlab)) but I cannot seem to use this for the 2D case. I wish to evaluate

```
integrand = @(x1,x2) mvnpdf([x1,x2],[0,0],[1,0;0,1]);
integral2(integrand,-10,10,-10,10)
```

but receive the error

```
X and MU must have the same number of columns.
```

I know I need to specify the integrand function to perform element-wise operations but my attempts have been futile. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for researching old questions before asking a new one ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
integrand = @(x1, x2) reshape(mvnpdf([x1(:), x2(:)],[0,0],[1,0;0,1]), size(x1));
```

Matlab documentation of `integral2` states that:

> All input functions must accept arrays as input and operate
>       elementwise. The function Z = FUN(X,Y) must accept arrays X and Y of
>       the same size and return an array of corresponding values.

For example for the case above, `integral2` passes two 14 by 14 matrices to `integrand`. The `x(:)` makes a one-dimensional vector out of the matrix passed by `integral2`. This is needed in order to provide `mvnpdf` with two column vectors as it is expected in this case. `mvnpdf` then returns a column vector of density values which must be reshaped (using `reshape`) to make the dimensions the way `integral2` is expecting them to be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this the standard way to do this?

Comment: @Freakalien I am not aware of a "standard" way of doing this as such. I have seen and used techniques similar to this (`reshape`ing and `repmat`ing) to get the dimensions right. None of these are elegant and in fact they tend to decrease readability. This is one of those situations where the default vectorised nature of Matlab makes things complicated and ugly. I’ve seen very similar issues in R which also has a vectorised data model.